# postgres query taking very long and not sure why

Tags: postgresql, index

I have a table where I'm selecting the following info but it is taking VERY long (like a minute):

```
 select controller, action, original_url from page_views order by id desc;
```

I have an index set up on id here:

```
Indexes:
    "page_views_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_page_views_on_params" gin (params)
```

If I do an explain analyze, I get:

```
explain analyze select controller, action, original_url from page_views order by id desc;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan Backward using page_views_pkey on page_views  (cost=0.09..70578.83 rows=1449712 width=68) (actual time=0.025..2721.362 rows=1445610 loops=1)
 Planning time: 0.088 ms
 Execution time: 2794.296 ms
(3 rows)
```

The fact that this takes so long concerns me. Is this just a reflection of it streaming ~1.5 million rows over the network?

What would be the next step to see if this could be made faster?

thx

#### edit 1

```
explain (analyze, buffers, timing) select controller, action, original_url from page_views order by id desc;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan Backward using page_views_pkey on page_views  (cost=0.09..70578.83 rows=1449712 width=68) (actual time=0.077..818.684 rows=1445618 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1068173 read=60798
   I/O Timings: read=178.285
 Planning time: 0.085 ms
 Execution time: 905.648 ms
(5 rows)
```

and shared_buffer / table_size:

```
select current_setting('shared_buffers') AS shared_buffers, pg_size_pretty(pg_table_size('page_views')) AS table_size;
  as shared_buffers |  as table_size 
--------------------+----------------
 244MB              | 444 MB
(1 row)
```

#### edit 2

per comment below, I ran `reindex TABLE page_views` - the index was same size and performance appeared to be increased like 5%:

```
explain (analyze, buffers, timing) select action, controller, id from page_views order by id desc;
                                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                                       
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan Backward using page_views_pkey on page_views  (cost=0.09..70576.70 rows=1445928 width=23) (actual time=0.024..818.932 rows=1445929 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=1068451 read=60806 written=4
   I/O Timings: read=179.327 write=0.066
 Planning time: 0.082 ms
 Execution time: 881.825 ms
(5 rows)
```

Comment: This looks like a really slow index scan. Can you add the output of `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)`?  It _could_ be a bloated index - being much bigger then needed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I added the info that I think you're asking for. It definitely seems faster on second query (which is what these queries would reflect) so possibly a cold / hot cache issue.

Comment: 244MB shared_buffers is an extremely small value. And yes the second execution being much faster is indeed caused by caching effects. but 1.6 million buffer reads for 1.4 million rows sounds too high. See if `reindex page_views` changes anything

Comment: thx @a_horse_with_no_name - I ran `reindex TABLE page_viewss` - the size of index was the same at 444 MB and it appeared to run a few percentage points faster. Since this instance is on heroku, I am not sure if I can update the shared_buffers size - I'm looking into it but suspect if I spend more $$$, I can.

Comment: Which of the timings you give is reproducible (i.e. upon repeated execution, with a hot cache)?  Can you be more precise about "like a minute"?

Comment: `reindex` will not change the size of the index, it will only optimize the storage of the index.

Comment: Yep @jjanes - the initial load was about a minute and the subseuqent was a few seconds (possibly longer due to streaming results over the network). Certainly conceivable that a cold cache was part of it but feel that there are probably optimizations which more experienced dba's would have insight into.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  If the index is bloated, then reindexing it will shrink it.  It will re-order the leaf pages of the index, bu that is usually not of great importance.  Are you perhaps confusing REINDEX with a CLUSTER of the table?

Comment: If good performance from a cold start is import, then one thing you could try is to CLUSTER the table on the `page_views_pkey` index.  Another would be check your random_page_cost and seq_page_cost.